# Formulate an example of a bounded continuous function on $(0,1)$ for which there does not exist a sequence of step functions which uniformly converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence

I am having trouble coming up with such a function. I know that every continuous function on $[0,1]$ has a sequence of step functions which uniformly converges.

Please help/guide me in formulating such an example.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** if $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x)$ exist then we can extend $f$ to a bounded continuous function on $[0,1]$ by setting $f(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ and $f(1)=\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x)$.

**Hint 2:** When I want a function whose limit at $0$ does not exist, I consider $\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$.